# Get email frequency using grouping sets

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with emails logs and need to check the email frequency. using grouping sets retrieve email count hourly, daily, weekly, monthly  and yearly.
Can anyone send me an example.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,create_time) [year]
, DATEPART(mm,create_time) [month]
, DATEPART(WEEK,create_time) [week]
, DATEPART(dd,create_time) [day]
, DATEPART(hour,create_time) [hour]
, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM your_table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (DATEPART(yyyy,create_time)
    ,DATEPART(mm,create_time)
    ,DATEPART(WEEK,create_time)
    ,DATEPART(dd,create_time)
    ,DATEPART(hour,create_time)) 
ORDER BY [year], [month], [week], [day], [hour]
```

To group by multiple fields, just group columns in parentheses: 
    ,(DATEPART(yyyy,create_time), DATEPART(mm,create_time))

Here's sample output, including the year/month grouping:

```
year    month   week    day     hour    c
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0       12
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1       1
NULL    NULL    NULL    1       NULL    219
NULL    NULL    NULL    2       NULL    467
NULL    NULL    1       NULL    NULL    124
NULL    NULL    2       NULL    NULL    216
NULL    1       NULL    NULL    NULL    1899
NULL    2       NULL    NULL    NULL    1419
2015    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3750
2016    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    7446
2015    8       NULL    NULL    NULL    391
2015    9       NULL    NULL    NULL    891
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply ! 
I have added ID column to the grouping sets,not getting if it is Hourly/weekly/daily/monthly generated.

```
SELECT ID, DATEPART(yyyy,create_time) [year]
, DATEPART(mm,create_time) [month]
, DATEPART(WEEK,create_time) [week]
, DATEPART(dd,create_time) [day]
, DATEPART(hour,create_time) [hour]
, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM your_table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(
     (DATEPART(yyyy,create_time),ID)
    ,(DATEPART(mm,create_time),ID)
    ,(DATEPART(WEEK,create_time),ID)
    ,(DATEPART(dd,create_time),ID)
    ,(DATEPART(hour,create_time) ,ID))
ORDER BY [year], [month], [week], [day], [hour],ID
```

Result

```
Month   Week    Daily   Hour C
NULL    NULL    NULL    0   12
NULL    NULL    NULL    0   471
NULL    NULL    NULL    0   176
NULL    NULL    NULL    0   145
NULL    NULL    NULL    0   633
NULL    NULL    NULL    0   13
NULL    NULL    NULL    0   24
NULL    NULL    NULL    0   2
NULL    NULL    NULL    0   324
NULL    NULL    NULL    0   555
```

Comment: What does ID represent - is that a unique ID per row or is that a grouping variable (like an email type ID or something)? If it's a grouping variable, then your approach is fine - it will group by ID/hour, ID/day, ID/month, etc.

Comment: Yes, It is a grouping variable( like email typeID, as you mentioned).  Thank you for your help!